# cakephp foreign key dropdown not working in scaffold

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

My schema is quite simple-
Each user has an id and name. 
There are jobs which belong to a user. Actual schema-

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
  `name` varchar(20) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
   id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED ,
  `type` int,  
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) references  users(id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My JobsController looks like this-

```
<?php
class JobsController extends AppController {
    public $scaffold;
    public $name = 'Job';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className'    => 'User',
            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id'
        )
    );

}
```

And UsersController as-

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $scaffold;
    public $name = 'User';


    public $hasMany = array(
        'Job' => array(
            'className'     => 'Job',
            'foreignKey'    => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

**Problem:**

When I visit `http://hostname/Jobs/add` I can see a drop-down for user but its empty. 
I've created few users which I can see from `http://hostname/Users/`

Why is drop-down empty? I am able to add jobs but when I view them, user field is shown empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Associations belong in the **Model**, not the controller.

In *app/Model/User.php*:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasMany = array('Job');
}
```

In *app/Model/Job.php*

```
class Job extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Job';
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
}
```

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks for pointing that out and going extra mile to provide code.